# I get this type error question while writing my solidity Programming

Tags: solidity, error, string, uint256

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity 0.6.1;

contract ExampleMapping1{

    mapping(uint => string) names;

    struct Name{
        string yourName;
    }

    function MyNames(uint _rNo,string memory _yourName) public{
        names[_rNo] = Name[_yourName];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some work. You have to create an instance or mapping to access the struct object. You cannot access it directly. Try something like this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity 0.6.1;

contract ExampleMapping1{
    struct Name{
        string yourName;
    }
    mapping(string => Name) public nameStruct;
    mapping(uint => string) names;

    function MyNames(uint _rNo,string memory _yourName) public{
        names[_rNo] = nameStruct[_yourName].yourName;
    }
}
```